# Failing Azure DevOps build pipeline if the build has any warning

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Hi There I have been asked to modify all current CI yml pipelines to fail if the C# API or WEB app has any warning, also it needs to be in its own stage in the process.

I have been looking on the net and can't find any code please can someone help with the code needed

thanks

Comment: What is the name of the task that you exactly use? PowerShell, Bash, DotNetCoreCLI
, or maybe another one? Can you provide sample code?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for your reference.

1.You could add a PowerShell task in the stage, and then run the Rest API: [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to traverse the warning messages in the previous task. And use logging commands to control the [results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#properties-2).

PowerShell script:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjName}/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/timeline?api-version=5.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$count = 0

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

ForEach( $issues in $response.records.issues )
{
  if($issues.type -eq "warning")
  {
    echo $issues.Message
    $count ++
  }
  
} 

echo $count

if($count -ne 0 )
{ 

  Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
   
}
```

Pipeline Output:

[image]

2.Using Extension task: [Build Quality Checks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks&targetId=ca4e4e67-3099-4c62-9ea9-bef80e0cc70a&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) is another option.

[image]

Add this task to your target stage to check the warnings.